# Replace of cron job/cron tabs-- Windows Scheduler

Tags: windows, php, cron, javascript

I want to know that there is any way to create an script on windows machine in `PHP` that should run after an interval, let's say every after 15 minutes.

Currently I'm doing it using javaScript, but this is not an efficient way to do that as the browser tab have to be opened always (if user close it by mistake--Script will no longer execute).

So I want to know is there any method to call the script and continue to call it and it should continue to execute even the tab or browser is closed. One possible technique is to set an infinite loop (but this is not a good approach).

So any help is appreciated.

Note: If you don't like it so leave it but please don't give it negative, as my account will be blocked

Comment: `Note: If you don't like it so leave it but please don't give it negative, as my account will be blocked`  Well, I hate to break it to you, but that's probably the *point* of the downvoting.  This is a very basic question (which is very poorly asked) that took me all of 10 seconds to find the answer to on Google... so maybe the downvoters don't want you asking more unresearched, poorly asked questions.

Answer (score 1):

[What you're looking for is Windows Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7).

If you want to configure it for every X minutes, (instead of days/weeks/months), you need to go into the Advanced properties, [as noted on this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4250516/1668244).